# jquery animate width disrupts the flow of other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bunch of divs in sort of a grid pattern, and when a tile div is clicked on, i want it to expand out to the right to show a previously hidden div. however, during the animation, the surrounding tile divs are put out of position for a moment before going back to their correct position after the animation completes. I would like it to just smoothly slide out to the right. click on the top left tile to see most closely what I mean.

Here's the JS code, but I assume there has to be some CSS tweak. see the fiddle for CSS.

```
$('.tile').on('click', function(){
    $(this).find('.sparkline').show();

    $(this).animate({
        width : '326px'
    },
    600, 
    function(){

    }); 
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nup6x/)

All the Less:

```
.tiles{
  .tile{
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
    height:72px;
    margin:8px;
    background-color:#F1F1F1;
    border:1px solid gray;
    border-radius:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    .origMetrics{
      width:154px;
      display:inline-block;
    }
    .sparkline{
      display:inline-block;
      width:154px;
      height:53px;
      float:right;
    }
    .seperator {
      margin: 0 15px 5px 15px;
      border-color:black;
    }
    .metrictitle{
      display:block;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
      text-align:center;
    }
    .metricvalue {
      display:inline-block;
      text-align:left;
      width:auto;
      margin-left:10px;
      font-size:25px;
    }
    .metrictrend {
      float:right;
      margin-right:10px;
      margin-top:5px;
    }
    .positive{
      color:green;
      img{
        position:relative;
        bottom:15px;
        left:15px;
      }
    }
    .negative{
      color:red;
      img{
        display:none;
      }
    }
    .even{
      img{
        display:none;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing the showing of the sparkline `div` inside of the `.animate()` complete callback function.

The sparkline container was being shown and taking up space in the DOM prior to the animation being completed. This led to the appearance of a jump in the animation.

For an even cleaner look, you can use `.fadeIn()` instead of `.show()` on the sparkline container.

```
$('.tile').on('click', function () {
    $(this).animate({
        width: '326px'
    }, 600, function () {
        $(this).find('.sparkline').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

In addition, in IE and Firefox it appears that the `display: inline-block` style on the tiles was interfering with the `overflow: hidden` that gets applied as part of the animation. When you utilize `inline-block`, I would highly suggest also setting the `vertical-align` property accordingly. In your case, I believe `vertical-align: top` would be the best setting for the tiles.

```
.tile{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width:auto;
    height:72px;
    margin:8px;
    background-color:#F1F1F1;
    border:1px solid gray;
    border-radius:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PChBS/7/)

Comment: so i know you fixed that jsfiddle, but for some reason on my page this doesn't solve it, the tile to the right of the tile being animated always pops downwards before popping back up to the right spot. any other thoughts as to why that might be? i don't want to recreate my whole page in the fiddle

Comment: Is there any additional CSS or JS related to the sparkline container, its siblings, or its parents that is not included in the jsfiddle? Also, is the version of jQuery you are using the same as the one on the jsfiddle?

Comment: adding all my Less for that section above

Comment: I updated my answer and the jsfiddle. I noticed an issue similar to what you described when I tried it on IE and Firefox. Check to see if the changes I made fix it in your code as well.

Comment: never would have gotten it without that! thanks that did it! +1